# In the new Tor browser bundle how to change identity programmatically?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

In the new Tor browser bundle is there any way to change new identity programmatically, since there is no Vidalia bundle?

Comment: Do you mean how to request creation of a new Tor circuit using a command line tool or API?

Comment: yes  exactly thats what I am looking for

Comment: You also asked a similar question here: http://tor.stackexchange.com/q/1414/88 Please don't ask the same question more than one time. It might take some time until one finds an answer.

Comment: You can download Vidalia yourself in Tor website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of some ready-made solution. However you could write an expect script for your shell:

The first part reads out the cookie file and calls the `expect` script

```
#!/bin/sh
COOKIEFILE=/var/lib/tor/control_auth_cookie
if [ -f $COOKIEFILE  ]; then
  COOKIE=$(hexdump -e '32/1 "%02x""\n"' $COOKIEFILE)
else
  echo "Cookie not found"
  return 1
fi

expect -f tor-newnym.exp $COOKIE
```

The `expect` script is just an idea. Maybe you'll need to set some additional values later:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set cookie [lindex $argv 0]
spawn telnet 127.0.0.1 9050
expect -exact "Trying 127.0.0.1...\r
Connected to 127.0.0.1.\r
Escape character is '^]'.\r
"
send -- "AUTHENTICATE $cookie\r"
expect -exact "250 OK\r
"
send -- "signal NEWNYM\r
"
expect -exact "250 OK\r
"
send -- "quit\r"
expect eof
```

This takes the cookies and sends it to the Tor process. However please be aware that the port of your Tor process might be another one. Furthermore the chain of command might be too fast, so you have to slow it down.

Comment: Thanks  1) in windows how can I mae it work?

Comment: `Tor` uses now a `ControlSocket` by default. Replace the `spawn` and first `expect` command above with `spawn nc -U {$HOME/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor/control.socket}` (if you have `BSD`'s `netcat`) or use `telnet -u [socket]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change identity using green Tor button. This is the best choice. However, you still can activate Vidalia manually and change identity that way. (not recommended)

Comment: Thanks but i want to change progmatically means thru script or command line

Comment: HI  I am still looking for solution for windows

Answer (score 0):

On GNU/Linux, there is the `tor` command and we can change the country exit node with a single command `tor -ExitNodes {fr}` for France or `tor -ExitNodes {de}` for Germany (Deutschland) for example. But to create a new circuit to change the IP address, I have to press Ctrl+C and start the command again.

I don't think there is an interactive shell, or command parameter to create a new circuit. If you do it programmatically, you will have to kill the process and start it again, so if someone has an easier solution to change the identity, your welcome.

A cleaner method would be to use the NEWNYM signal like @Jens Kubieziel said but it would be easier if it was available as a command parameter like `tor -new-identity` or `tor -new-circuit`.