# authenticate telnet connection

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, authentication

I tried connecting to tor in TBB 3.5.1, OS X 10.8.5 using `telnet localhost 9151` but since CookieAuthentication is set it requires authentication.

From the [manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en)

> CookieAuthentication 0|1 If this option is set to 1, allow connections
>   on the control port when the connecting process knows the contents of
>   a file named "control_auth_cookie", which Tor will create in its data
>   directory. This authentication method should only be used on systems
>   with good filesystem security. (Default: 0)

I checked RFCs and other sources for TELNET/telnet but I couldn't find any information on this matter.

How can I authenticate using the cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Locate the file `control_auth_cookie`
2. Enter `hexdump -e '32/1 "%02x""\n"' $COOKIEFILE` where `$COOKIEFILE` is the location of the file from step 1.
3. Copy the output
4. Open a shell and enter `telnet 127.0.0.1 9151`. If you can't get a connection check if Tor listens on that port. Other versions listens on port `9050`.
5. When you see a prompt enter `AUTHENTICATE $OUTPUTFROM2` where `$OUTPUTFROM2` is the output  you copied from step 2.
6. Tor prints `250 OK` and you're done.

If you like to put the steps above in a program, I'd suggest a shell script plus `expect`. In the [answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/1453/88) to '[New tor bundle how to change identity programmatically?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/1438/88)' I described how to do it for `NEWNYM`. You just need to insert the line `send -- "getinfo circuit-status"` at the correct line.

Comment: Great, it works. Before accepting it, how would you script the whole thing to just get the fingerprint of the exit relay node with `getinfo circuit-status`? S. http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1422/how-can-i-get-a-relays-fingerprint

Comment: I checked `getinfo info/names` but there's no direct way to get the fingerprint of the exit. Do you know how to get and parse it in `expect_out`?

Comment: Hi Jens, thanks! This answer inspired me to add a FAQ entry discussing each of tor's connection and authentication scenarios: https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#can-i-interact-with-tors-controller-interface-directly